# How do I customize formish error messages?

Tags: python, webforms, formish

I'm using [formish](http://ish.io/embedded/formish/) to handle web forms but I don't like the automatically generated error messages when validation fails. Where do I customize those error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place for feedback on formish is in the google groups which is linked to from the http://form.ish.io page..

As for customising the error messages, the best way would be to create your own validator (which is pretty simple, have a look in the validatish module). However, you've inspired me to think about making all of the validators take a custom argument for each type of message... I'll have a think about that one. If you struggle customising your own errors, drop into the google group...

Comment: I wound up creating a validator that wraps another validator, catches the validation exception, and raises one with the desired message.

Answer (score 0):

I've added custom messages to the validatish module for you .. If you get it from github, you'll see how it works (you pass a dictionary of messages to the validate function or object - e.g. `Required(messages={'required': 'dont forget it!'}) )`

If you need a release for it quickly, let me know..